# How to ensure all frames are read and processed with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, video

I am trying to use OpenCV to load a video file or access video stream from webcam but I'm unable to access all frames.

The video file is captured with the FPS of 60 but in my code I am only able to access a few frames per second. I tried using the threaded version of OpenCV, `imutils`. It works better but I still cannot access full frames.

In my code below, I use the threaded version video reader to load video file and resize it to smaller size to reduce the processing power required.

After the frame is grabbed successfully, I will so some image processing work (in the future). But now even with this boilerplate, I can at most read only a few (10+) frames and the results are stuttering. Is there a way to resolve this?

```
import cv2
from imutils import resize
from imutils.video import VideoStream

vs = VideoStream(src="./video.MOV").start()

while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    if frame is not None:
        frame = resize(frame, 800)

        # some heavy analytics work

        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

**Experiment**

I ran an experiment to calculate number of frames loaded and average time taken for each `imshow` function on both my iMac and an Ubuntu machine rocking Intel Core i5-7400 @ 3.00Ghz with a 1080p monitor.

The video (h264) has a duration of 1:03 min and of size 185.7MB.

iMac can only load a total of 414 frames while the Ubuntu machine can load a total of 2826 frames.

Average time take for `imshow` function for both machine is `0.0003s`

Comment: Do you have high CPU usage or is one core utilized 100%? Does it work a lot better without resizing?

Comment: I am running this on a 3.4GHz iMac 5k with 24GB RAM without any intensive program running in the background. Without resizing the frame drop is much obvious.

Comment: Does that mean your CPU usage is very low at runtime? Is another videoformat like mp4 h264 also so slow and can you log how often (millisecond timestamp) the imshow function is called? Is it called more than once per frame?

Comment: @Harry I have updated the post with the experiment.

Comment: Still i would be interested in how your cpus on the systems are utilized in comparison, the clock speed does not really matter for me. However, i suspect that opencv uses different core technologies to grab/decode the frames. Possibly you can force it to use ffmpeg - then the results should be the same on both systems: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/da7/videoio_overview.html - alternatively get out what technology is used currently on the mac and tell me.

Comment: @Harry I checked and can confirmed that OpenCV is using FFMPEG as backend, just like how's its with the Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Thats great. But it limits my ideas about what could be wrong ;-) ...you already enabled benchmarking so can you tell if it is the vs.read() function that is 8 times slower on the mac compared to the ubuntu machine?

Comment: Any updates on this? When I use vs.read() I'm losing frames as well. I'm on Windows and using ffmpeg

Comment: I am facing this problem, too. It seems to be still hard

Answer (score -3):

Basically, you just load the video and display, so there isn't any reason that you get low fps like that except that you are using a Macbook with Retina screen. Maybe it's the reason causes slow video display because the Retina screen has a lot more pixels, and it might take time for the compositing engine to render your image on the screen. I suggest to use an external screen.

Comment: please consider giving an actual solution. The problem is in the code. That way you can help other people with a similar problem